# unable to add configure field to drupal view

Tags: views, entities

I added a new field to an existing content type. But when I try to add same field or any other field to the view, I don't find it in the list except few.

Eg: I added image field to content type. Then I clicked on 'edit view' for which I want to add this image field. Then I click on add field under fields section. I don't find the fields of image body or anything, except title field others.

Can anybody help me sort out this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your view is not a Content view.  Create a "Content" relationship on the view, and all the content type fields configured on your site will become available to add to the view.